# how to zoom a div with :hover but not the image inside

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to zoom a container from both sides when hovered but not the image inside of it and the divs floating around must became smaller while zoom one of it.
You can check the result I wanna achieve at: https://www.bitforex.com/  you can find it at half page level
I developed this:
`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/Diana_rossa/419wko53/7/

The problem is I can't figure out how to zoom on both sides the div at same time
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-position: center` to achieve this effect if you use the image as a background image.

Update: by placing a few of those inside a flex container it looks almost ready.

```css
.frame {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/150');
  height: 150px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-position: center;
}

.frame:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <div class="frame">
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow.You are a monster.Can I marry you?

Comment: @IT goldman you better Marry this person hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/5925951/pexels-photo-5925951.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanna a divorce.It's similar to the original but when hover a div the others also reduce their height.Is it possible with pure CSS or I need javascript?